# How to substitute values ​enclosed in double quotes

Tags: perl

I need to substitute values ​​enclosed in double quotes. The goal is to replace commas with question marks and replace double quotes surrounded by double quotes with hyphens.

Comment: Did you miss out a `|` before your `(rm` ?

Comment: Please define "double quotes surrounded by double quotes". Should `"x"x","x"x",` become `"x?x","x?x",` ? Are you trying to process CSV?

Comment: @jhnc "x"x","x"x", -> "x?x","x?x", This is correct.and I expected.

Comment: @jhnc I try to process OFS files like CSV. For example, 
 ```AAA/BBB/VAL1="BBB",VAL2="CCC".```

Comment: unescaped, unbalanced quote detection can't be done unambiguously. `"x","x","x",` could become `"x|,|x","x",` or `"x","x|?|x",`

Comment: what are "OFS files"? Outlook form storage?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. But this is OFS generator.  https://ofs.etelej.com/           
I think CSV is as same as OFS.

Comment: Both cases look like dialects of CSV. It's almost never the case that you want to write your own CSV parser in (any) shell, rather than switching to a language that already has an available CSV parser (which is pretty much any general-purpose programming language you can think of; shell is *not* a general-purpose programming language).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
use Text::ParseWords;

my $dlm = ","; # 区切り文字を定義

open(RH, "<", "from.csv");
open(WH, ">", "to.csv");
while(<RH>){
  chomp;
  my @parsed = parse_line($dlm, 1, $_);
  
  for(my $i=0; $i<=$#parsed; $i++){
    $parsed[$i] =~ s/$dlm//g;
  }
  
  print WH join($dlm, @parsed)."\n";
}
close(WH);
close(RH);
```